# can we draw bar chart by using S7GraphView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, charts, s7graphview

HELLO ALL
i want to draw bar chart for my app and i feel S7GraphView is easier then core-plot...as i tried to download and use core plot but its not happening ...for me

can any one knows how to draw bar graph by use of S7GraphView?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S7GraphView doesn't draw bar graphs.
You can choose to use Core-Plot (it's very difficult to use it) or to draw rectangles with quartz